# installing ubuntu on imac g5 without OS

Tags: 12.04

I have recently got an iMac g5 from an auction but it does not have any OS. I tried to boot it using a USB drive with necessary commands on its terminal but it won't boot. Finally, I tried to boot it using CD for Ubuntu installation, but still it does not seem to respond. Could you tell me how or what I should do in this situation? While buying, it's told that the system is working good in all OS.

Could you help me figure out this problem.

Thanks.